# SQL that work on ORACLE and not work on DB2

Tags: oracle, db2

I have an SQL that put the comma before house address number. 
This SQL work great on ORACLE but if I paste it in DB2 (vers. 7.2) 
is not work.

```
SELECT C, REGEXP_REPLACE(C,'(\s+\S*\d+\s*$)',',\1')     
FROM TABLE(                                             
    VALUES                                              
     ('VIA MILANO 123     '),                           
     ('VIA MILANO A123    '),                           
     ('VIA 11 MILANO AA123')                            
           ) AS T(C)
```

Is there anybody that can tell me why ? or if I can convert it please ?

Thanks a lot 
Denis

Comment: `regexp_replace` has been introduced to db2 with v11.1 (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0054107.html)).

Comment: The ibm i-series v.2 docs for regular expressions do not mention the character class escapes for \s, \S, \d.  This may explain the behaviour on i-series. Suggest you recode or open a ticket with ibm support to get their confirmation whether these character-class-escapes are supported in 7.2 or not.

Comment: Sorry but this post is not a duplicate, so please pay attention at the "duplicated" post... this one was about how to put a comma before house number... and the present post is about why a SQL is work on Oracle and is not work on DB2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  C
, REGEXP_REPLACE(C, '(\s+\S*\d+\s*$)',', \1')
, REGEXP_REPLACE(C, '( +[^ ]+ *$)',', \1')
FROM TABLE
(
  VALUES                           
    ('VIA MILANO 123     ')
  , ('VIA MILANO A123    ')
  , ('VIA 11 MILANO AA123')
) AS T(C);
```

Both `REGEXP_REPLACE` functions from the example above work on my DB2 7.3 for IBM i.
If they don't work for you, you should open a Case with IBM support.

Comment: Thanks a lot all, I just download the PDF manual from IBM ... named "IBM i
DB2 for i SQL Reference 7.1" and here I have the REGEXP_REPLACE command at page 460. 

Mark the SQL that you send me (and thanks a lot) 
is not work. 
So do you think I must open a ticket at IBM ? 
How can I do this please ? 
Thanks again all

Comment: If you work with 7.2, you should refer to the corresponding documentation, and not the one for another version. [Regular expression control characters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm?view=kc#rbafzregexp_like__regexp_likecontrol). As for opening Cases: you should ask your system administrator for this.

Comment: Dear all, 
I found the problem (for future users) 

My client access emulation (the green screen) 
has the code-page on Italian-Euro in the communication configuration. 

Now that I put it on 037 United States it's work :-) 

Thanks a lot all for your support. 
Denis